# Выравнять текст по центру

Tags: вёрстка, css

Верстаю навигацию для сайта, возникла проблема с цифрами страниц, как их выравнять по центру этих картинок ?

[image]

в html выглядит так

```
<div class="basecont">
<span><img alt="Назад" title="Назад" src="/sat/2/templates/my/image/right.png"/></span>
<div class="navigation">
 <span>1</span> <a href="http://127.0.0.1/sat/2/page/2/">2</a>  
</div>
<a href="http://127.0.0.1/sat/2/page/2/"><img alt="Вперед" title="Вперед" src="/sat/2/templates/my/image/left.png"/></a>
</div>
```

css

```
.navigation {
    display: inline-block;
     margin-top:20px;
}

.navigation span {
    background: url("../image/hover_pag.png") no-repeat;
    color: #7bc4eb;
    text-align: center;
    padding:15px;
    padding-top: 16px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}

.navigation a {
    background: url("../image/pag.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    color: #7bc4eb;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding:15px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: у вас больше 99 страниц в  принципе не предусмотрено?) Не нравится идея сделать кнопку из 3 частей (лево-цифры-право)? Тогда эта заморочка сама отпадет.

Comment: Я если честно хз как это решено в dle, задача была такая)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/7soft/adhrD/

При `display:inline-block;` содержимое выравнивается по базовой линии ([пример](http://webdevelopernotes.ru/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/2-inline-block.html)). Я поставил выравнивание по верху (`vertical-align:top;`).
Ну и лучше картинки, отвечающие за интерфейс, ставить через css =)

Comment: Проблема еще возникла в ie6-7, блоки типа вперед-назад не совсем правильно отображаються

Скрин - http://s019.radikal.ru/i614/1204/8a/21fc980fe70b.jpg

Comment: Попробуй заменить в кодах этих кнопок div на span...

Comment: Не помогло

Comment: Обновил, посмотри по ссылке в ответе

Comment: Неа,ничего не изменилось

Comment: А, не, не обновилось. Вот - http://jsfiddle.net/7soft/adhrD/3/

Comment: Все отлично, спасибо за помощь :)

Answer (score 2):

Наверное, `padding-top: 16px;` убрать.

Comment: Не, как это на текст влияет ? Этими паддингами я картинки выравнял. Иначе бы их вообще небыло.

Comment: Дайте, пожалуйста, ссылку на страницу с проблемой.